# Correct Score and Correct Result Probabilities

Tags: probability

Say there is a game where you have to predict scores for sports games (0-0, 1-0, 1-1, 2-1 etc.). You are awarded points for correct result (home win, draw, away win) and correct score (always more for correct score). You have access to the odds of every event.

Sometimes, the most likely score won't be the most likely result (e.g. the most likely score being 1-1, but the most likely result being for a particular team to win).

How would you work out which score is favourable to pick? Naturally you'll either want to pick the most likely score overall, or the most likely score out of all the scores belonging to the correct result.

This is the logic I have so far (the higher of the two numbers is the better pick):

```
    correctResultPoints / aResultOdds + correctScorePoints / aScoreOdds
    correctResultPoints / bResultOdds + correctScorePoints / bScoreOdds
```

Where odds are in decimal format (a bet of 100 on odds of 1.5 returning 150, and calculating implied probability by doing 1/odds). CorrectResultPoints is what you get for a correct result, and correctScorePoints is what you get *on top* of that for getting the score exactly correct.

The reason I ask is because although the logic seems right, the events are inherently dependent on each other and the formula doesn't take this into account.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple and straigthforward. Enumerate all possible events (that is scores) as $E_1,\dots E_n$. We say that $E_i$ and $E_j$ are compatible provided they correspond to the same *result.* Next, for each $i$ let $p_i$ be a probability (that is $1$ divided by odds, right?) of the $i$-th event.

If we pick event $E_j$ then the expectation $M_j$ of our points is

$$M_j=p_j\cdot correctResultPoints+$$ $$correctScorePoints\cdot \sum\{p_i: E_i \mbox{ and }E_j\mbox{ are compatible}\}.$$

So we have to pick an event $E_j$ with the largest value of $M_j$.

Good luck! ;-)